# How to do online training in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

How to use a stateful RNN in online training in keras. So at each time step I get one element of one sequence.

I have sequence1: e11 ->e12 - >e13

Sequence 2: e21 ->e22 ->e22

Seq 3.......

How can I treat each element as it comes? I can use a stateful rnn to treat each element of the same sequence but sequence1 is not related to sequence2 so I need to switch to stateless Rnn between sequences(I also have many sequences). In keras the statful parameter of the rnn layer cannot be changed. So how can I change it between sequences?

Also, what is the difference if I consider a statfull rnn or if I consider a statless rnn and treat sequences as below. So I feed each sequence as multiple samples to the same rnn:

Seq1: e11->e12 Seq2:e11->e12->e13 Seq 3: e21->e22 Seq4: e21->e22->e23 ......

In this case I am reefeeding the rnn each sequence in steps. Is this the same as stataful rnn. What is the difference between statefull rnn or refeeding the sequence with the continuation.

Comment: Do you have any particular algorithm for online training in mind? As far as I know, it’s not something available out of the box, you probably need to implement from the scratch.